# category list with cutom post count

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

i want to show category list with custom post type count. but i have two different post types in every category. how can i do that . please help. this is my code:

```
<?php
    $category_object           = get_queried_object();
    $current_category_taxonomy  = $category_object->taxonomy;
    $current_category_term_id  = $category_object->term_id;
     $current_category_name  = $category_object->name;

    $args = array(
        'child_of'            => $current_category_term_id,
        'current_category'    => $current_category_term_id,
        'depth'               => 0,
        'echo'                => 1,
        'exclude'             => '',
        'exclude_tree'        => '',
        'feed'                => '',
        'feed_image'          => '',
        'feed_type'           => '',
        'hide_empty'          => 0,
        'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'orderby'             => 'name',
        'separator'           => '',
        'show_count'          => 1,
        'show_option_all'     => '',
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
        'style'               => 'list',
        'taxonomy'            => 'category',
        'title_li'            => __( $current_category_name ),
        'use_desc_for_title'  => 0,
    );
    wp_list_categories($args);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box this cannot be done, as the post counts on each term is singular, there is no breakdown by post type.

In order to do this, you will need to output the markup yourself, and query for the counts yourself.

**This will be slow/heavy/expensive.**

So first we start with the current term/taxonomy:

```php
$category_object           = get_queried_object();
$current_category_taxonomy  = $category_object->taxonomy;
$current_category_term_id  = $category_object->term_id;
$current_category_name  = $category_object->name;
```

Then we grab all child terms that aren't empty:

```php
$children = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy' => $current_category_taxonomy,
        'parent'   => $category_object->term_id,
    ]
);
```

And loop over each term:

```php
foreach ( $children as $child ) {
    //
}
```

Now inside that loop we need to check how many posts are of your particular post type, lets say the `changeme` post type:

```php
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'changeme',
        $term->taxonomy  => $child->term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ];
    $q    = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<li>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . ' ( '. intval( $q->found_posts ) . ' ) </li>';
    }
```

Notice we used the `found_posts` parameter. At this point, it's just a matter of wrapping the whole thing in a `<ul>` tag, and expanding the markup to match what you want. You have the term object inside the loop to print out URLs etc with.

Don't forget, this is expensive/slow/heavy, you will want to cache this, perhaps using a transient, or if you have an object cache or Elastic search present.

Or you could just register another taxonomy specific for this post type, and avoid all of this.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_taxonomy_posts_count_func($atts)
    {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
        ) , $atts));
        global $WP_Views;
        $term = $WP_Views->get_current_taxonomy_term();
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            $term->taxonomy => $term->term_id,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        if ($posts)
        {
            $res = count($posts);
        }
        return $res;
    
    }
    add_shortcode('my-taxonomy-posts-count', 'my_taxonomy_posts_count_func');
```

1. add codes in your theme/functions.php
2. put the shortcode in your content, like this:

   [my-taxonomy-posts-count post_type="my-custom-post-type"]
3. replace the "my-custom-post-type" with your specific post type slug
4. replace the shortcode [wpv-taxonomy-post-count] with [my-taxonomy-posts-count post_type="my-custom-post-type"]

Change code as per comment

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but it shows no category

Comment: $cats = wp_list_categories();

Comment: echo wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'show_count' => true,
    'taxonomy'   => 'campaign_action' //i guess campaign_action  is your  taxonomy 
) );   try this     campaign_action  change   your   taxonomy

Comment: yes it not taxonmy

Comment: can  you give me  screen short share your  category list  with url

Comment: http://cloud.maxproduction.az/drive/s/lvmlFKjsUNZg5J8RRsLznluukvHMBP

Comment: please  check the answer on the post  as  per post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111787/discussion-between-dharmishtha-patel-and-gidromasservis-qsc).